# Scriptlet does not print out value

Tags: jsp

I tried following JSP code.
A did print out the contents inside dto, however, B did not. How come?

A.

```
name: <%= dto.getName()%> <br>
```

B.

```
name: <% dto.getName();%> <br>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<% %>` This is scriptlet tag. Whatever you write inside this will go into JSPs service method. You can write simple java code inside this(You can not create new methods).

`<%= %>` This is expression tag. Whatever you write inside this will be considered as arguments of `out.print();` and though you don't need to use `;` while using expression tag like case A.

In your case B if you want to print you have to write

```
<%
    out.print(dto.getName());
%>
```

But it is bad practice to use scriplets since long. You can use expression language or JSTL instead.

If you are using eclipse then you can see generated servlet of JSP in which you can see how scriplets works.

```
\Workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\work\Catalina\localhost\[AppName]\org\apache\jsp
```

[image: Info]